# How to use a Database Variable Name in dynamic SQL with visual studio for a SQL Server Project?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2017

Is there a way in Visual Studio to use a *Database Variable Name* in dynamic SQL for a SQL Server project? Or, is there a alternative solution?

I have a project for a SQL Server database with references to other database projects, each with *Database Variable Name* set. For example, the *Database Variable Name* would be `$(PROD)` and I have used this *Database Variable Name* to publish the project using a TEST database.

My current project is using dynamic sql, and I would like to be able to publish this project using either a PROD or TEST database. I would prefer not to use a `@database` variable, and simply using `SELECT @database = $(PROD)` does not work.

For example, below I have dynamic SQL in a stored procedure with `QUOTENAME(@database)`, and I would like to be able to replace the `@database` variable and use `$(PROD)` or some way to set the database name when I publish the project.

```sql
DECLARE 
  @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @database SYSNAME,
  @schema SYSNAME,
  @table SYSNAME;
CREATE TABLE #src_pk(SrcColumn VARCHAR(100));

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT QUOTENAME(b.[COLUMN_NAME]) AS [Column] 
                  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@database) + N'.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE_CONSTRAINTS] a 
                  JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@database) + N'.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE] b 
                    ON a.[CONSTRAINT_NAME] = b.[CONSTRAINT_NAME] 
                 WHERE a.[CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA] = ' + QUOTENAME(@schema, '''') + N'
                   AND a.[TABLE_NAME] = ' + QUOTENAME(@table, '''') + N'
                   AND a.[CONSTRAINT_TYPE] = ''PRIMARY KEY'' '
INSERT INTO #src_pk EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019; the project language is in SQL; and, my project platform is SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Why not pass `$(PROD)` as a parameter? You'd be better off tagging with the language you're using in Visual Studio and showing us your code.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. Do you mean pass `$(PROD)` as a parameter in `sys.sp_executesql`?

Comment: I mean use a parametrised query in your application code. Considering we don't know what that language is, I can't tell you how.

Comment: It is database project in Visual Studio, so the language is TSQL. if you want to use project variable in any assigments, you need to put quotes around it, like SELECT @database = '$(PROD)'

Comment: Thanks @Piotr. I actually read that somewhere too while putting this question together; but, I didn't test it as I didn't think it would work.  Yes, `SELECT @database = $(PROD)` does not work and `SELECT @database = '$(PROD)'` does work. I can publish the project now and it will be `SELECT @database = 'TEST'` or whatever I set the _Database Variable Name_ value to.

Comment: SQLCMD variables are applied to the batch text using brutal text replace before the batch is send to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the project deployment variable directly in the dynamic SQL, just be sure to correctly quote it:

```
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT QUOTENAME(b.[COLUMN_NAME]) AS [Column] 
                  FROM ' + QUOTENAME('$(DatabaseName)') + N'.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE_CONSTRAINTS] a 
                  JOIN ' + QUOTENAME('$(DatabaseName)') + N'.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE] b 
                    ON a.[CONSTRAINT_NAME] = b.[CONSTRAINT_NAME] 
                 WHERE a.[CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA] = ' + QUOTENAME(@schema, '''') + N'
                   AND a.[TABLE_NAME] = ' + QUOTENAME(@table, '''') + N'
                   AND a.[CONSTRAINT_TYPE] = ''PRIMARY KEY'' '
```